# How to develop the simple chat application in my project using with ruby on rails 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2

I need to develop a simple chat application in my app. It should look like gtalk and it should support the two way chat.

Can anyone please help me? Is there any code you can post me as reference?

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye